# How to interactive a silently installing msi? (Progress data and cancel it)

Tags: installation, windows-installer, silent-installer

For some reason, we are delivering a product with our own install GUI, that means, we will run the msi installation silently background.

By using the MSI API "MsiInstallProduct", I can install the product silently, but I have no idea how can I get the progress data of this installation and how can I cancel it.

Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample project that appears to do what you are referring to:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/msiinterop.aspx

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE June 2018**: Although the tool shown below is no longer available for download, I found it via Wayback machine. I assume it is OK and legal to link to it, seeing as the tool was freeware. Updated links below.

<del>**UPDATE**: *This tool from Wise is regrettably not downloadable anymore*. I am not sure if it is OK to distribute it either. It seemed to be a free tool distributed as part of their main Wise Package Studio suite, but I don't think it is open source. I wish they would release it as an open source tool.</del>

The Wise packaging products have been discontinued due to a number of [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wise_Solutions,_Inc.).

---

I believe you can get the progress via the MSI API, but if I were you I would just show the progress bar from the MSI itself after invoking the install via **msiexec.exe**.

MSI supports several different installation levels (full, completely silent, basic GUI, reduced GUI etc...). In your case it sounds like you want a basic UI. This yields a progress bar where you can hide the cancel button, and optionally show a completion modal dialog:

**Install silently with progress bar, no cancel button and no modal dialog at end:**

```
msiexec.exe /I "Test.msi" /QB-!
```

To avoid having to construct these silly msiexec command lines manually, use the **msi command line builder tool** from Wise: [http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20140402194132/http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe) (**resurrected from Wayback machine**).

Please run the download by [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) for safety.

[image]

---

***Related***:

- [installation using msi.exec open help options every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164005/installation-using-msi-exec-open-help-options-every-time/22166685#22166685)
- [Silent Install of MSI](https://serverfault.com/questions/30068/silent-install-of-msi/67001#67001)
- [How to install an MSI package from a command prompt](https://serverfault.com/questions/89020/how-to-install-an-msi-package-from-a-command-prompt/276765#276765)
- [How do I force the Windows MSI installer to perform a complete install?](https://superuser.com/questions/240861/how-do-i-force-the-windows-msi-installer-to-perform-a-complete-install/296512#296512)
- [Silent Installer with custom selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166534/silent-installer-with-custom-selection/22170346#22170346)

Comment: I will get you a vote but not for my answer.
We are not using the msi GUI because it's not fit our product's style, so we are provide a cooler progress bar for it, all I need is the progress data to set our bar.
The msi's basic GUI is not acceptable.

And I still cannot cancel it from pure API right?

Comment: Here is a sample of how to work with MSI billboards and progress bar: http://sourceforge.net/projects/msiprogramming/ . If this isn't what you need, perhaps look through the resources at: http://www.installsite.org

Comment: Remember to click the "view all files" button (otherwise you get only a demo).

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify an external UI handler using MsiSetExternalUI or MsiSetExternalUIRecord before MsiInstallProduct (the latter is nicer, but has a higher MSI version requirement). The function you specify will be called for each message Windows Installer wants you to process. This will give you the data, and a chance to respond tell it to cancel. If you require MSI 4.5 or later, you can use an embedded external UI handler DLL, which does not require a bootstrap.