# How can I set a wait cursor for potentially long running custom actions in wix?

Tags: wix

I have an installer built with wix that works well - except that one of my Custom Actions can potentially take a long time.  To make my install kit more user-friendly, I'd like to change the mouse cursor to a spinning hourglass (or something similar) while the Custom Action completes.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are new features in WIX, I think the way to achieve this is with a custom progress bar. This is a little more involved to get working than you might think.

Here is a thread I would read in its entirety: [How to interactive a silently installing msi? (Progress data and cancel it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659924/how-to-interactive-a-silently-installing-msi-progress-data-and-cancel-it/1662786#1662786)

And here is a direct link to source code for an external progress bar as well as other, similar code for Windows Installer use: http://sourceforge.net/projects/msiprogramming/files/msiprogramming/ . This code looks OK, but somewhat dated. You may have some updating to do.

Make sure to try the MSI command line builder from Wise - it helps a lot to forget the command line issues as a source of errors when you try your coding.