# Rollback setup issue in wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have a setup using WIX.
At the time of installing after installing some files it get rollback without display any error or exception.
What might be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a verbose log file for your package.

```
msiexec.exe /I "Package.msi" /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

Then you need to inspect what is wrong inside the log. Open it and **search for "value 3" in the log** as explained in WIX creator [**Rob Mensching's blog**](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log).

For help with msiexec.exe's complex command line, [use this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1659958/129130). It is a front end GUI that generates the msiexec command lines for you. Very quick and reliable.